# Calculating distance using information from two spatial dataframes

Tags: r

How do I calculate the distance between points on one spatial data and another?

I have spatial data (Data A) of where people work and another of places they shop (Data B). Meaning persons in Data A can have multiple points in Data B (if they shop at different places). In the example below, I have 10 individuals who work at 10 different locations and 30 shopping locations with an ID variables showing which individual shops at the location.

I would like to calculate the distance between each individual's workplace and their shopping locations. E.g in the data below individual with caseid 5 shops at 4 different locations, hence the distance from that person's workplace to each of the 4 locations. Is there a simple way to do this in R.

This is an example of my dataset

```
Work <- structure(list(X = c(0.290865745861083, 0.172332319431007, 0.91694570844993, 
                        0.836186615284532, 0.434236856177449, 0.620326127391309, 0.407956667244434, 
                        0.372948321513832, 0.732449576724321, 0.273215322522447), Y = c(0.728168945061043, 
                                                                                        0.571332231163979, 0.925216830568388, 0.569567700615153, 0.680816388688982, 
                                                                                        0.886224129470065, 0.843231112230569, 0.992756717605516, 0.753016141941771, 
                                                                                        0.88617284828797), ID = c(1L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                  9L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                                                  ))

shop = structure(list(X = c(0.248519139597192, 0.0820750859566033, 0.509946328122169, 
                      0.263646977255121, 0.450909543782473, 0.3655308149755, 0.973895246163011, 
                      0.468441155040637, 0.89834801107645, 0.143394310493022, 0.53004258708097, 
                      0.0176214659586549, 0.553407138446346, 0.218308804556727, 0.532563277985901, 
                      0.297094692708924, 0.0840529787819833, 0.310307152802125, 0.0460839839652181, 
                      0.824119930155575, 0.425772953778505, 0.334572859574109, 0.418677452486008, 
                      0.360124682076275, 0.233770624734461, 0.19114388525486, 0.186111402697861, 
                      0.718537265667692, 0.479000998428091, 0.157951993634924), Y = c(0.962770452024415, 
                                                                                      0.687904139515013, 0.362791520776227, 0.853135082637891, 0.870199563913047, 
                                                                                      0.827481605811045, 0.402690515853465, 0.275655945530161, 0.621536011807621, 
                                                                                      0.860662709223107, 0.985142867313698, 0.0219723240006715, 0.615980780683458, 
                                                                                      0.589729696745053, 0.258363580796868, 0.974228937411681, 0.0439547575078905, 
                                                                                      0.749408702598885, 0.303944817045704, 0.555796873988584, 0.84082814026624, 
                                                                                      0.30526150111109, 0.320820331806317, 0.486546019790694, 0.792565869400278, 
                                                                                      0.988222383661196, 0.405008672038093, 0.852051933994517, 0.0803902524057776, 
                                                                                      0.809713886352256), ID = c(5L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                 3L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                 1L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                          "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `sf` package:

```
> library(sf)
 Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1
    
> verts = merge(Work, shop, by="ID")
```

link the workplaces to the shop locations by matching the IDs to get:

```
> head(verts)
  ID       X.x       Y.x       X.y       Y.y
1  1 0.2908657 0.7281689 0.1911439 0.9882224
2  1 0.2908657 0.7281689 0.5300426 0.9851429
3  2 0.6203261 0.8862241 0.2337706 0.7925659
4  2 0.6203261 0.8862241 0.3103072 0.7494087
5  3 0.3729483 0.9927567 0.8983480 0.6215360
6  3 0.3729483 0.9927567 0.1433943 0.8606627
```

Then apply over rows and compute the length of a linestring constructed by the points:

```
> distances = apply(as.matrix(verts[,2:5]),1,function(r){st_length(st_linestring(matrix(r,2,2)))})
```

To give a vector of distances:

```
> distances
 [1] 0.90915797 0.63115002 0.61883267 0.51333412 0.67881318 0.94796435
 [7] 0.62295899 0.89941982 0.74594454 0.47605670 0.43711750 0.57220392
[13] 0.51133268 0.44613883 0.76239136 0.49688003 0.53337058 0.72773376
[19] 0.03045599 0.14738707 0.13377062 0.25799345 0.56399597 0.41854902
[25] 0.62215457 0.36876407 0.85041940 0.61297297 0.21986132 0.60617805
```

If you want to know which workplace/shop corresponds to each distance, add an identifier to the `shop` data frame:

```
> shop$SHOP=1:30
```

and then:

```
> verts = merge(Work, shop, by="ID")
> head(verts)
  ID       X.x       Y.x       X.y       Y.y SHOP
1  1 0.2908657 0.7281689 0.1911439 0.9882224   26
2  1 0.2908657 0.7281689 0.5300426 0.9851429   11
3  2 0.6203261 0.8862241 0.2337706 0.7925659   25
```

then you can add another column to that data frame with the distance:

```
> verts$distances = apply(as.matrix(verts[,2:5]),1,function(r){st_length(st_linestring(matrix(r,2,2)))})
> head(verts)
  ID       X.x       Y.x       X.y       Y.y SHOP distances
1  1 0.2908657 0.7281689 0.1911439 0.9882224   26 0.9091580
2  1 0.2908657 0.7281689 0.5300426 0.9851429   11 0.6311500
3  2 0.6203261 0.8862241 0.2337706 0.7925659   25 0.6188327
```

showing workplace 1 shops at shop 26 at a distance of 0.90981580, and at shop 11 at a distance of 0.6311500 and so on.

If your coordinates are in a known coordinate reference system then create an `sfc` vector with the correct coordinate reference system identifier and take the length of that object. For example, if you are working in WGS84 EPSG:4326 GPS lat-long coordinates, then:

```
> apply(as.matrix(verts[,2:5]),1,function(r){st_length(st_sfc(st_linestring(matrix(r,2,2)),crs=4326))})
 [1]  30777.32  61788.15  40153.48  23045.44  75508.33 104090.58  46179.13
 [8]  39881.31  71253.27  88538.00
```

returns distance in metres.

Comment: thank you. But is there a way to confine the calculated distance between and shopping locations to the specific cases? I have revised the question to include an example of my data

Comment: Thank you, Spacedman. That was very helpful.

Comment: if my x and y locations are Decimal degrees is there a way to transform the distance to meters?

Comment: @Ekow_ababio yes, see latest edit and also read up on coordinate reference systems in the `sf` package.

Comment: awesome :). Again, thank you for all the help